# Can you grant someone else permission to start your Minehut server in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minehut

I am trying to decide what server hosting site would be better for a private survival Minecraft multiplayer world. I have already used Aternos before and it has a feature that lets you give permission to start your server to someone else, without giving them full permissions. Does Minehut have anything similar?

I have tried to research this on google, but the information is unclear.

### First result when searching "Minehut server access" on google:

https://forums.minehut.com/topic/11973-how-to-give-a-friend-access-to-start-my-server/

> They can just do /join [SERVER]

Is this part of a URL or a Minecraft command? If it is part of a url, what is the rest of it? If it is a Minecraft command, how would they enter it with the server offline?

### Second result:

https://forums.minehut.com/topic/18533-giving-friend-the-server-access/

> Anyone can start a server with "/join [server]" in the lobby.

What is "the lobby"?

### Conclusion:

My research suggests that there is some way for someone to start the server *(but not stop it)* without full access, but I don't understand how this works.

What is the full process to start someone else's Minehut server and what is the process to allow someone else to start it?

Comment: I would not recommend free hosting services - I used to use them and they were a bit of a pain.

Comment: I do not know much about Minehut, but I'm pretty sure that it does have a lobby accessible through "mc.minehut.com". See https://minehut.com/go/howto-java for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on the minehut website under How do I join a server (https://minehut.com/go/howto-java), You can connect to the minehut lobby by adding `mc.minehut.com` as a server.

This is where you can execute your commands etc.

Once you have connected to the lobby, you can execute the commands from within minecraft.

> ## Get Started
>
> Open Minecraft and click “Multiplayer”, then click “Add Server”. You’ll be taken to this screen, where you’ll enter “mc.minehut.com” into the “Server Address” field. Give it a name (such as “Minehut Lobby”), then click “Done.”
> [image]
>
> ## Almost There…
>
> The Minehut Lobby will be added to your server list for easy access. Once it’s connected, select the server and click “Join Server”.
> [image]
>
> ## That’s It!
>
> You will be automatically transported to the Minehut Lobby, where you can chat with whoever’s online and log into your server. Have fun!
> [image]

Comment: Does the lobby allow you to start a server that hasn’t been started from the website?

Comment: If the server has been stopped explicitly using the dashboard, you can't start it from the lobby, but if it has been stopped due to inactivity, you can simply use the `/join [server]` command to start it again.